# Runtime functions in v8

Tags: javascript, c++, v8, profiler

1. In v8, ic.cc, i see functions like `RUNTIME_FUNCTION(Runtime_KeyedLoadIC_Miss)`. I don't understand how are they invoked. Is there some connection with `TailCallRuntime(Runtime::kKeyedLoadIC_Miss, arg_count, 1);`  from ic-ia32.cc?
2. What is the difference between `Runtime_KeyedLoadIC_Miss` and `Runtime_LoadIC_Miss`?
3. Can I profile these runtime functions using some c++ profiler? I want to see how much time is spent on a subset of these runtime functions.

Comment: 3) I see 2 possible solutions: a. Use a RAII timer (v8 even had them somewhere, but I struggle to find it right now, or you can implement yourself). b. [quote from mrale.ph] > Your best bet then is either hardware counters based tool like Linux perf for which V8 has support (see v8/tools/ll_prof.py --help for more details)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you should be able to invoke a runtime function like this
`__RT_impl_Runtime_StringCharCodeAtRT(args, isolate)`

In JavaScript, you can run v8 with --allow_natives_syntax and invoke runtime functions with %:
`var code = %_StringCharCodeAt(string, k);`